# How can I build an Adobe Air project with Maven?

Tags: apache-flex, maven-2, air, adobe

Has anyone successfully built an Adobe Air application with Maven?  If so, what are the steps to get it working?

I have been trying to use [flex-mojos](http://code.google.com/p/flex-mojos/) to build an Air applications.  When I set the packaging type to "aswf", as suggested in the [DashboardSamplePom](http://code.google.com/p/flex-mojos/wiki/DashboardSamplePom), Maven complains that aswf is an unknown packaging type.  I also found their [air-super-pom](http://svn.sonatype.org/flexmojos/repository/info/flex-mojos/air-super-pom/2.0-alpha4/air-super-pom-2.0-alpha4.pom), but could not figure out how to reference it as the parent of my POM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an article called [Building an AIR Application](https://docs.sonatype.org/display/FLEXMOJOS/Building+an+AIR+Application) on the mojos website wiki.  It should be able to help you.

Comment: https://flexmojos.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/FLEXMOJOS/pages/622647/Building+AIR+applications

Answer (score 2):

When a plugin declares a new packaging type, like 'aswf', you need to declare it as an extension. In your top-level pom, add the extensions element to the plugin config.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>...</groupId>
  <artifactId>...</artifactId>
  <extensions>true</extensions>
...
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been searching for an answer to this problem as well.  There are a couple sites that have proved helpful, though I don't have a full solution yet.

Check these for possible leads:

- http://blogs.citytechinc.com/bgloff/?p=17
- http://jchristie.wordpress.com/2009/01/11/compiling-an-air-application-with-maven-and-flex-mojos/

AS for the packaging type, most of the information I've found indicates that rather than using aswf as the package type, you'll need to use swf and then convert the compiled swf into your air executable by creating an exec tax to invoke adt.jar  The links above will show you how to do that much.

As for the air super pom you found, I think there are a few different ones... But to use any super pom, you need to have your flex maven project declare the super pom as the parent, with a block similar to this:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.sonatype.flexmojos</groupId>
    <artifactId>flexmojos-air-super-pom</artifactId>
    <version>3.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

However just extending the parent pom may not be enough to get your swf building - once again, see the links above for a more detailed treatment of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I created an AIR Maven template, you can find the details in this github project: https://github.com/branscha/tmplt-airapp. The question is quite old so the versions/frameworks in my solution might not be suitable for you any more. The Flex/Air situation has changed a lot during the last years.

Characteristics of my solution:

1. I use a Mavenized Apache SDK (13.0), you should probably do the same
   thing for your projects to be independent of an external Maven
   repository. The procedure to mavenize the SDK is not too difficult.
2. Flexmojos 6.0.1
3. The hello-world app can be turned into an Android
   app.
4. The packaging is 'air' (i.s.o. aswf that was mentioned above)

Answer (score -2):

In my case I simply created a new maven project using the
org.graniteds.archetypes graniteds-tide-seam-jpa-hibernate archetype and got this error.  I don't know anything about flex, but simply wanted a sample project using Seam.  This seemed like a good candidate.  But I get

unknown packaging type:swf

even though
 the <extensions>true<extensions> is present in the plugin definintion of the generated POM file.

I read somewhere else that this reqires a beta version of maven.  Why the heck is sonatype allowing archetypes that depend on beta versions of maven in their repository?

Comment: true, I meant it as a comment, not an answer.